# spark/pyspark integration with HBase

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hbase

Is it possible to connect Spark 2.4.3 connect to a remote HBase 1.3.2 server?

I've tried using this version:

https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/com/hortonworks/shc-core/1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11/

but there seems to be a compatibility issue:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;

```
spark-submit --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ /hbase-read.py
```

read.py is just a simple read for testing:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate() 

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
data_source_format='org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'


catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"testtable"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "col1":{"cf":"cf", "col":"col1", "type":"string"}
    }
}""".split())

df = sqlc.read.options(catalog=catalog).format(data_source_format).load()
df.show()
```

I know this shc-core version works with Spark 2.3.3 but what are my alternative options for 2.4+ ?

I've built from shc-core from source but when I reference the jar, I receive this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor

even though I've referenced all the necessary jars:

```
spark-submit --jars /shc/core/target/shc-core-1.1.3-2.4-s_2.11.jar,/hbase-jars/hbase-client-1.3.2.jar /hbase-read.py
```

Answer (score 2):

1)**Is it possible to connect Spark 2.4.3 connect to a remote HBase 1.3.2 server?**

> Yes it is possible. you can connect either using Hbase client or
>   using shc-core as well.

2) **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(Lorg/json4s/JsonInput;Z)Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;**

> This means there is one more json4s jar with different version. Check
>   the full stack trace. from which class it's being called. remove the
>   additional jar.

3) **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor**

> This jar shc-core-1.1.3-2.4-s_2.11.jar Uses hbase version >=2.0 in
>   which TableDescriptor Class has been introduced. In Hbase 1.3.2
>   version there is no such class instead it has HTableDescriptor. If you
>   wish to work with latest shc-core version, you have you use hbase
>   version >=2.0,  If you your hbase version < 2.0 then use compatible
>   shc-core version ( <= v1.1.2-2.2)

4)**I know this shc-core version works with Spark 2.3.3 but what are my alternative options for 2.4+ ?**

> shc-core is pretty much straight forward one. it works with any 2.4
>   as well. it will provide sql plan for spark on how to convert
>   different type columns to bytes  (back and forth ). Make sure you are
>   picking right jar for your hbase one.